# Get VSCode to format differently by subfolder

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a project structure like this

```
+-project
  +-.clang-format
  +-.git
  +-.gitattributes
  +-.vscode/settings.json
  +-src
  | +-somefileA.cpp
  | +-someFileB.cpp
  +-third_party
    +-ffmpeg
    | +-.clang-format
    | +-.vscode/settings.json
    | +-src
    |   +-.git
    |   +-.gitattributes
    |   +-src
    |     +-ffmpeg.c
    +-zlib
      +-.clang-format
      +-.vscode/settings.json
      +-src
        +-.git
        +-.gitattributes
        +-src
          +-zlib.c
```

I need `ffmpeg.c` and `zlip.c` and `someFileA.cpp` to all be formatted differently when viewing in VSCode. Some use tabs of 4, some use tabs of 8, some don't use tabs but indent by 2, some have an 80 column line limit, some have 100 column line limit, etc..

Is there a way to get VSCode to format these differently in the same instance of VSCode ?

I see I can [add multiple "root" folders to a "workspace"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces) in VSCode but:

(a) these aren't "root" folders, they're subfolders

(b) I'm not using workspaces, yet another file that is unrelated to my project that would have to get synced.

(c) ideally I wouldn't have to have to manually add more folders as more third party libraries are added. They're sub folders of a bigger project so ideally it would just work.

The same way `.clang-format` and `.gitattributes` work by covering the subtree they're in, I tried putting a `.vscode/settings.json` with different settings but no luck.

Are there other solutions?

Comment: you can have a look at [Path Settings](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tbremer.path-settings), according to the code it allows an array of settings to change